# Using __FUNCTION__ in a macro

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Using:

```
#define DEBUG_FOO(foo) fprintf(stderr, "foo is %x, currently in %s\n", foo, __FUNCTION__);
```

Will print:

```
foo is 0, currently in (null)
```

While using:

```
#define DEBUG_FOO(foo) fprintf(stderr, "currently in %s, foo is %x\n", __FUNCTION__, foo);
```

Will print:

```
currently in foo_bar, foo is 0
```

What is happening here? I would expect either both to work or both to have __FUNCTION__ as null.

The compiler used is the linaro arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: [Coudln't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/a7NWKlPKsDeaz6PT) in both gcc and clang. What is your compiler?

Comment: I have added in the compiler used.

Comment: @zenith People tell you to include a complete test case. That means a complete program that anyone can copy paste and run. This helps you as well, as to eliminate any other code you have, that noone else can see now,  that could cause the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Works fine for me with gcc from Debian stable for x86.

Comment: A wild guess: when you invoke `DEBUG_FOO`, is the argument `foo` actually an expression of type `unsigned int`?  If for example it's actually an `unsigned long`, this could explain the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can trigger this problem with wrong data types. E.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    uint64_t foo = 0;
    fprintf(stdout, "foo is %x, currently in %s\n", foo, __FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}
```

If compiled for amd64 architecture, it works fine:

```
foo is 0, currently in main
```

For for x86 (`gcc -m32 test.c`):

```
foo is 0, currently in (null)
```

This is how variadic function arguments expands, and initial program have a bug. In that particular case format argument should have been `"%"PRId64` and `%x` expects `int`.

With reversed order it kind of works because pointer have better width handling, bit it is still wrong.

In case of gcc/clang, `-Wformat` usually catches this kind of mistakes at compile time and gives a warning.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, my foo was 24 bytes. Simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

the old non-standard name was `__FUNCTION__`.  you should change all your code to use `__func__` now.  they were defined/declared slightly differently as well.

although it really sounds like your compiler is buggy.  if `__func__` works, i'd chalk it up to no one testing `__FUNCTION__` anymore.